# QLineedit disabling/re-enabling.

Tags: qt, qtgui, qlineedit

I have an equation with four variables, only 3 need to be defined for the program to run. When 3 of the parameters have been defined (via lineedits in my GUI) I'd like the fourth to be greyed out. I only know how to link two parameters at the moment by disabling one lineedit when another is edited. e.g.

```
void WaveformGen::on_samples_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->cycles->setDisabled(true);
}
```

So when samples is edited I disable another lineedit called cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one single slot:

```
class WaveformGen {
private:
    QList<QLineEdit *> m_lineEdits;
private slots:
    void lineEditTextEdited(const QString &text);
    ...
};

WaveformGen::WaveformGen()
{
    ...
    // create an ordered list of line edits:
    m_lineEdits << ui->lineEdit1 << ui->lineEdit2 << ui->lineEdit3 << ui->lineEdit4;
    // connect all to same slot:
    foreach(QLineEdit *lineEdit, m_lineEdits) {
        connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), this, SLOT(lineEditTextEdited(const QString &)));
    }
}

void WaveformGen::lineEditTextEdited(const QString &str)
{
    // iterate over all lineEdits:
    for (int i = 0; i < m_lineEdits.count() - 1; ++i) {
        // enable the next lineEdit if the previous one has some text and not disabled
        m_lineEdits.at(i+1)->setEnabled(!m_lineEdits.at(i)->text().isEmpty() && m_lineEdits.at(i)->isEnabled());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the better way to do it @SageDO

Comment: Could I get a little more explanation on what's going on in the code please? I don't fully follow.

Comment: @SageDO I added some comments.

Comment: @svlasov thanks, I was stuck trying to understand what conditions enabled the lineedits.

Answer (score 0):

Make one slot, connect as many `textEdited(const QString &arg1)` from diffrent lineEdits as you need to, and then in the slot's body retrieve signal sender using the `QObject::sender()` method

Comment: How do you suggest using `sender()` to find the line edut which was not edited?